# How to use showScreen method with parameter in Lighswitch Html

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I am trying to launch a screen programatically.  If the screen has no parameters, myapp.showscreen(screenName,null,null) works fine.

I know the second parameter in the method is an array off screen parameters but I can't find the correct syntax. I have tried myapp.showscreen(screenName,[{"paramName":"paramVal"}],null) but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
myapp.showScreen(screenName, [88], null);
```

for example to pass the value 88 to a screen parameter. Check two things:

- the screen has a property, **marked as parameter** (there is a check box to tick)
- **move the parameter to the top** on your data item list (to the left of your screen designer window)